# Storing into a list schedule from a .txt file

Tags: python

The first part below does what I want by separating it by week works how I want it, but when I try to store it in the schedule list that iterates over I,

Here is my code:

```
schedule_file = open("sch2019.txt", "r")
schedule_list = schedule_file.readlines()
for x in schedule_list:
```

This is the output of the code:

```
week   1 : { ('LAR','CP'), ('KCC','JJ'), ('NYG','DC'), ('BB','NYJ'), ('CIN','SS'),  ('DB','OR'),  ('WR','PE'), ('GBP','CB'),  ('AF','MV'), ('PS','NEP'), ('HT','NOS'), ('IC','LAC'), ('TT','CLV'), ('SF','TBB'),  ('DL','AC'),  ('BR','MD') }

week   2 : {  ('SS','PS'), ('BB','NYG'),  ('DC','WR'), ('SF','CIN'),  ('IC','TT'),  ('JJ','HT'),  ('PE','AF'), ('KCC','OR'), ('LAC','DL'),  ('CB','DB'),  ('AC','BR'),('NOS','LAR'), ('TBB','CP'), ('NEP','MD'), ('MV','GBP'),('CLV','NYJ') }

week   3 : {('NYJ','NEP'),  ('PS','SF'), ('HT','LAC'),('NYG','TBB'), ('NOS','SS'),  ('DL','PE'),  ('OR','MV'), ('DB','GBP'),('LAR','CLV'),  ('CB','WR'),  ('CP','AC'),  ('MD','DC'), ('BR','KCC'), ('CIN','BB'),  ('AF','IC'),  ('TT','JJ') }

week   4 : {  ('TT','AF'),  ('SS','AC'), ('CIN','PS'), ('NEP','BB'), ('CLV','BR'),  ('OR','IC'),('TBB','LAR'),  ('MV','CB'),  ('CP','HT'), ('LAC','MD'), ('KCC','DL'),  ('JJ','DB'), ('DC','NOS'), ('WR','NYG'), ('PE','GBP') }
```

I want to store each week into a list schedule, but I don't know how to approach it.

What I tried doing is

```
schedule_file = open("sch2019.txt", "r")
schedule_list = schedule_file.readlines()
schedule = []
for x in schedule_list:
    for i in x:
        schedule.append(i)
        print (schedule)
```

But all it does is further separate it. 
How would I separate the list into iterations for schedule?

what i want it to be like:

```
Schedule[1]← {(LAR,CP), (KCC,JJ), (NYG,DC), (BB,NYJ), (CIN,SS), (DB,OR), (WR,PE),(GBP,CB), (AF,MV), (PS,NEP), (HT,NOS), (IC,LAC), (TT,CLV), (SF,TBB), (DL,AC),(BR,MD)}

Schedule[2]←{(SS,PS), (BB,NYG), (DC,WR), (SF,CIN), (IC,TT), (JJ,HT), (PE,AF), (KCC,OR),(LAC,DL), (CB,DB), (AC,BR), (NOS,LAR), (TBB,CP), (NEP,MD), (MV,GBP), (CLV,NYJ)}
```

where each iteration of the schedule[i] contains the values from the corresponding week info from the text file

Comment: I am a bit confused about what output format you want. Would you be able to provide a small sample example?

Comment: what do you mean by a "list schedule"?

Comment: @Jay @NickMartin ````

Comment: you have strings, not dictionaries. You would have to parse it. Or use regex to get elements from string. Eventually use eval() to convert strings.

Comment: @furas how would i parse it?

Comment: I don't know what you exepect in `Schedule[1]` - single string, list, dictionary or set().

Comment: using `eval(string)` you could convert it to `set()`. For other structures you would have to build parse. You could use `regex` or normal string functions.

Comment: Yea I am still not 100% sure what output format you want. So it looks like the code that you have already separates the schedules into different weeks but I'm not sure what you actually want for the output.

Comment: @VROLL Can you accept answer below please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after, working Repl.it [here](https://repl.it/@n1ckdm/UnequaledExcellentDefragment).

This will parse each line into a list of fixtures (assuming I've got your input text file formatted correctly). This is then stored in a `Dict` with the week number as a key.

```
import re

with open('schedule.txt') as f:
  schedule = f.readlines()

def line_parser(line):
  p = re.compile("'[A-Z]{2,3}','[A-Z]{2,3}'")
  fixtures = []
  for match in p.findall(line):
    fixtures.append(match)
  return fixtures

schedule_list = {}
for week, line in enumerate(schedule):
  schedule_list[week] = line_parser(line)

# Print the 10th fixture in week 3:
print(schedule_list[3][9])

# Output: 'LAC','MD'
```

I suppose you could break this down further by splitting each fixture into a home/away string which is stored as a dictionary, but I'm not sure what output format you're expecting?

```
import re

with open('schedule.txt') as f:
  schedule = f.readlines()

def line_parser(line):
  p = re.compile("[A-Z]{2,3}','[A-Z]{2,3}")
  fixtures = []
  for match in p.findall(line):
    sides = match.split("','")
    fixtures.append({
      "home": sides[0],
      "away": sides[1]
    })
  return fixtures

schedule_list = {}
for week, line in enumerate(schedule):
  schedule_list[week] = line_parser(line)

# Print the 10th fixture in week 3:
print(schedule_list[3][9])

# Output: {'home': 'LAC', 'away': 'MD'}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! I am not very familiar with Python, so a lot of this syntax is new to me, but this is huge to help me with my project. Thanks Nick.

Comment: @VROLL No problem, we're all learning (please accept the answer though!)

Comment: sorry @NickMartin. Just did it. I am new to Stack Overflow.